# Chef-client run half copying cookbooks from site-cookbooks directory into cookbooks directory

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, devops, configuration-management, chef-zero

I've got a custom cookbook that configures my Jenkins servers.  There are 3 recipes in a custom cookbook. I'm using `librarian-chef` to manage my cookbook dependencies. Chef is being run in local mode and I use terraform to provision my nodes with Chef.

When I run `chef-client -z` it tries to copy my custom cookbook in the `site-cookbooks` directory into the `cookbooks` directory. The reason I say "tries" is because it only copies one of the recipes over, it doens't copy the other recipes or other cookbook files like `metadata.rb`. Ultimately I get errors on including the java cookbook in my recipe because it can't resolve that cookbooks dependencies.

If I manually log into the node and copy the directory over myself, everything runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is resolved in latest stable version of chef. You can try that

Comment: Apparently not, I'm using the latest version of chef.